# 2D Array - Menu in C

Tags: c, arrays, menu, 2d

My program is crashing.

Basically, the data is not passing through the array for the menu choice and I am wondering if anyone could check it over and see where the problem is.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print_main_menu(char menu_items[5][10], int number_of_items) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < number_of_items; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", menu_items[0][i]);
    }
}

int main () {
    char menu [5][10];
    menu [0][0] = "1 - Membership List";
    menu [0][1] = "2 - Waiting List";
    menu [0][2] = "3 - Committee List";
    menu [0][3] = "4 - Temporary List";
    menu [0][4] = "5 - Exit";

    /* 1 - Membership List */
    menu[1][0] = "1 - Whatever";
    menu[1][1] = "2 - Whatever";

    print_menu(menu, 5);

    getch();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off: you declared your function as `print_main_menu` but you are calling it as `print_main` but this should resolve into a compilation error.

Secondly: you are using the two dimensional array incorrectly, apparantly you are using it as a two dimensional array of C strings, but you declared it as an array of characters.
This would be the right declaration:

```
char* menu [5][10];
```

Lastly: a lot of the array indices are not initialized, which means that they can point **anywhere** which will most likely produce a segmentation fault and crash your application.

EDIT: I'm also unsure if it is possible to pass an array to a function like you are doing it. It is most likely not a good idea to do so.

Comment: Thank you all for your quick responses, It is now functioning. I just need to add in a choice system and I should be good.

Comment: You definitely *can* pass a array to function, but it's generally a bad idea since what it really does is pass a pointer to the first element (eg: `menu` becomes `&menu[0]`). It would be better to do this explicitly; ie, change `char* menu_items[5][10]` to `char*(*menu_items)[10]`. However, since `menu_items` is nontrivial, it would be even better to define a data structure to hold your menu items and pass that (or a pointer to it).

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration, I sometimes tried to pass an array to a function, but, as far as I can remember, was never successful. I agree with your opinion to encapsulate the menu in a struct of some kind.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your main problem is that you are assigning strings to individual characters. You'll need to change it to:

```
char * menu [5][10];
```

What I mean is that you're accessing the positions of individual characters and trying to store a whole string in there.

Comment: Fixed that Tnelsong, but I still have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should define your array as follows : `char * menu [5][10];`

And as argument instead of `char menu_items[5][10]` you should use `char *menu_items[5][10];`

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The above program has lot of errors. For starters correct the function call in main..from

`print_menu()` to `print_main_menu()`.